# Pruning coordinates in subarrays of a list conditional on them having non-real components

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list of 2D coordinates placed in subarrays of a data structure like the following:

```
testList = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {RandomInteger[{0, 32}], 2}], {i, 1, 10}];
```

And if I sneak in a few entries where 2D coordinates have non-real or non-integer component values (positive or negative Infinity values, etc.) is there a way to quickly prune these coordinates away?  In other words, I'd like to go through a data structure like `testList` and quickly delete any coordinate that has a positive to minus `Infinity` in it.

Is there a way to make something like the following work?:

```
Select[testList, {_Real, _Real} &];
```

What if `testList` is already flattened by one level?  Does the larger context of the data structure matter for `Select`?

The following works for `testList`, but is not exactly ideal:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[testList], i++,

  testList[[i]] = 
    Select[testList[[i]], NumberQ[#[[1]]] == True && NumberQ[#[[2]]] == True &];

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list is flattened, you can do:

```
 Select[testList, #[[1]] \[Element] Reals && #[[2]] \[Element] Reals &]
```

If it's not flattened, then you can map the select onto the testList:

```
Select[#, #[[1]] \[Element] Reals && #[[2]] \[Element] Reals &] & /@ testList
```

For example, if you have terms like `{Infinity,Null}`, `{2,Null}`, or `{5,-Infinity}` in the testList, these terms are rejected.